# First column is empty in excel i cannot read in php

Tags: php

I have developed a simple program to read the excel sheet and store it in the database. It was working fine but I cannot read a row which has first cell is empty. 
For example:
[image]

I cannot read the row which has its first column empty. Any suggestions please...

Comment: Suggestions based on what? Maybe you post relevant parts of your code along with the clear explanation of what you expect but doesn't work for you.

Comment: Post your code so far what you have tried. After that only anyone can help you out.